# Copy one worksheet to multiple identical workbooks using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook containing one worksheet ("DB Output" or Sheet 34) which I would like to copy to several (around 45) files in within the same folder.

None of the target files have an existing sheet named "DB Output" - the objective is to find a way to insert a copy of this sheet, forumlas and all, into each one.

The range of cells on that sheet that needs to be copied to a sheet of the same name in each book is A1:PE5

The sheet contains references to cells in the book it is currently in, however as the files which I am seeking to copy the worksheet to all share the same template, I want the references to be to the local file, not the original one.

I've tried looking at RDBMerge, however it seems that is for merging sheets, and while I do want to do that, it will not help me do it multiple times quickly.

Likewise I have looked on SO for similar situations, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898772/copying-data-from-multiple-worksheets-to-multiple-workbooks) is the closest, however my attempts to adapt that code have failed as I only have a single workskeet. Never the less, as it is always useful to inlcude what you have already tried, here is my existing attempt:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub splitsheets()
    Dim srcwb As Workbook, trgwb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, t1ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim trgnm As String
    Dim fpath As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'--> Set this to the location of the target workbooks
    fpath = "C:/file/path/"

    Set srcwb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In srcwb.Worksheets
        trgnm = ws.Name
'--> Change A1:B3 to the range to be copied to inside page
        Set rng1 = srcwb.Sheets(trgnm).Range("A1:PE5")

        Set trgwb = Workbooks.Open(fpath & trgnm & ".xlsm")
        With trgwb
            Set t1ws = .Sheets("DB Output")
        End With
'--> Change A1:B3 to the range where you want to paste
        rng1.Copy t1ws.Range("A1:PE5")

        trgwb.Close True
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

However this starts with the first sheet in the workbook that contains DB Output (the sheet to be copied) and gives an error that "NameOfSheet1.xlsm" does not exist in that directory (which it does not).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is that you want to copy the data from one workbook into 45 or so other workbooks. You said that a sheet with the name "DB Output" exists in all of the other workbooks already. Do you need to replace the data on the existing sheet with the new data or append data to the end?

Comment: Hmm, not quite, I better edit to be more clear. Each of the 45 books is identical (strcturally) I want to add a single sheet into each of these books. That sheet exists in a separate workbook. None of the existing 45 have the worksheet DB Output, I want to insert it in each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should copy from the active workbook to all files in a directory. If you need help modifying it to fit your specific use let me know!

Edit: fixed code to only copy A1:PE5 and save each workbook.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim path As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim wkbk As Workbook

    path = "C:\Test\"
    file = Dir(path)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Do While Not file = ""
        Workbooks.Open (path & file)
        Set wkbk = ActiveWorkbook
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "DB Output"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB Output").Range("A1:PE5").Copy Destination:=wkbk.Sheets("DB Output").Range("A1")
        wkbk.Save
        wkbk.Close
        file = Dir
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Please note that I did not add error handling so this could break if the active workbook is included in the directory you are trying to copy or if a sheet with the same name already exists in the workbook. If this is an issue let me know and I will add error handling.

Comment: Thanks so much for this: it's certainly doing something, it seems to open and closes each file, however when the process is complete, the worksheet DB Output hasn't been copied across, they appear (as far as I can tell) unchanged. No errors or stoppages are occurring.

Comment: Fantastic! It works almost perfectly, you're a gentleman and a VBA scholar. If I could ask one more piece of advice: the sheet is copying, however it is keeping the source formulas "links" in tact. That is to say, they are referencing various worksheets in the original file, whereas I want them to reference cells within the workbooks they are being copied to. Any advice on that?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to change that during the copy process, however after it has been copied the formulas could be changed based on the current workbook name before saving and closing. Can you tell me which columns contain formulas / give an example of the formulas being used?

Comment: Sure I think I'll mark this one solved and open a new question for this, it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035032/edit-formulas-of-multiple-workbooks-to-remove-external-references-change-the-r