# Edit formulas of multiple workbooks to remove external references / change the reference to the local workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have copied a worksheet into a batch of workbooks (around 45).

This worksheet contains formulas and references i.e. `=Sheetname!A1` and `=IF(Sheetname!A2=1, "this", "that").`

However when the sheet has been copied, these formulas have become

```
=[Original_Book.xlsm]Sheetname!$A$1
```

and

```
=IF([Original_Book.xlsm]Sheetname!A2=1, "this", "that").
```

I'd like a way to remove all of the "[Original_Book.xlsm]" references so that the formulas become local again.

Actual examples (the above being for illustrative purposes only

```
=[Survey_Checker.xlsm]Output!D42
```

Should become

```
=Output!D42
```

Likewise:

```
=INDEX([Survey_Checker.xlsm]QR1!E3:[Survey_Checker.xlsm]QR1!E9,[Survey_Checker.xlsm]Output!$G$17,0)
```

Should become

```
=INDEX(QR1!E3:QR1!E9,Output!$G$17,0)
```

and so on.

In fact, if there was a VBA method to remove every instance of the string "[Survey_Checker.xlsm]" from the worksheet (which is called "DB Output") in the cell range A1:PE5 across each file, I beleive that might work?

EDIT: Every single column between A1 and PE5 has a reference forumla in that needs removing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a version of the original macro with added code to fix the formulas.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim path As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim wkbk As Workbook
    Dim rCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    path = "C:\Test\"
    file = Dir(path)

    Do While Not file = ""
        Workbooks.Open (path & file)
        Set wkbk = ActiveWorkbook
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        On Error GoTo Sheet_Exists
        ActiveSheet.Name = "DB Output"
        On Error GoTo 0
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB Output").Range("A1:PE5").Copy Destination:=wkbk.Sheets("DB Output").Range("A1")

        For Each rCell In wkbk.Sheets("DB Output").UsedRange
            If InStr(rCell.Formula, ThisWorkbook.Name) > 0 Then
                rCell.Replace What:="[*]", Replacement:=""
            End If
        Next

        wkbk.Save
        wkbk.Close
        file = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub

Sheet_Exists:
    Sheets("DB Output").Delete
    Resume
End Sub
```

This is a macro that will simply remove the workbook reference from the formulas

```
Sub Example()
    Dim path As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim rCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    path = "C:\Test\"
    file = Dir(path)

    Do While Not file = ""
        Workbooks.Open (path & file)

        Sheets("DB Output").Select

        For Each rCell In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DB Output").UsedRange
            rCell.Replace What:="[*]", Replacement:=""
        Next

        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        file = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Outstanding, works like a charm. I really appreciate the effort you put in to giving me both solutions - they are both really useful. Thanks so much, I'll use these to improve my VBA as well!